# getBuyIntentExtraParams does not exist? aka how do I use Version 6 in-app billing APIs?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

The `getBuyIntentExtraParams` method described by [the Android Billing Docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) doesn't seem to work properly in my project.

I see that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/3) on github that suggests grabbing [the AIDL file from the Trivial Drive Android example application](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl), but even after doing this I can't get the v6 API working (I get a `cannot find symbol` error).

My call is as follows:

```
Bundle extraParams = new Bundle();
extraParams.putBoolean("replaceSkusProration", true);
String ownedSku = "someSkuAlreadyOwnedByTheUser";
ArrayList<String> replaceSkus = new ArrayList<String>();
replaceSkus.add(ownedSku);
extraParams.putStringArrayList("skusToReplace", replaceSkus);
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntentExtraParams(6, 
                         getPackageName(), sku, "subs", "BigOlRandomString", extraParams);
```

Everything else about billing seems to work fine... what am I missing here?

edit: I can definitely get API v5 working, as Android Studio is more than happy to let me use the `getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus` function.

Comment: 6 months later... I still don't know how to do this. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Hihi!

It sounds like your build isn't generating the `IInAppBillingService.java` from the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file. Or if it *is* generating the java file, then the generated version is not being referenced by your project. At the end of the day, the method declaration in the java file is what your code can reference to resolve the `cannot find symbol` error.

My specific project doesn't use AndroidStudio or gradle, so I can't comment on how to resolve any issues with this step. Google does provide some documentation on it, though: [Adding the AIDL file to your project](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl). I believe the directory and file locations need to be very precise for AndroidStudio to pick it up.

Be sure, once you *do*, resolve the `cannot find symbol` error that you're passing in an API version of at least `6` to the first parameter.

Hope this unblocks you 8 months later :D good luck!

Comment: Hi, Sophie! I am definitely picking up the .aidl file correctly, as v5 calls to it are all working. The v6 api calls just don't work; it seems they aren't actually built into the libraries Google has released so far, even though they're documented...